# Regular expression help - Youtube ID

Tags: java, android, regex

Can anyone please help me with getting the correct regular expression to capture only the video ID of a YouTube video please?

I'm trying to scrape all YouTube video ID's from a playlist page.

Here's an example of a playlist - http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCEC78997E3E2DAB4

So the video ID's would be:

LoXye6KBeCI

pnfudjQwjS8

KUzhAq04PzU

etc

I've never been able to get my head around regular expression, I was hoping someone might be able to help?

Comment: please post the playlist (or a portion) in the question rather than as a link

Comment: Shouldn't you consider using Youtube's API ?

Comment: HamZa, I've spent a long time coding this and everything works now apart from this simple regular expression. If I can get this to work I should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class to get query

```
URL url=new URL(yourYouTubeURL);
Matcher m=Pattern.compile("(?<=v=)[^&]+").matcher(url.getQuery());
if(m.find())
{
    m.group();//your Video id
}
```

Comment: This crashes the app with 'No successful match so far' in logcat using the example link I posted in my original question.

Comment: I've now got it to read the link now properly, but adding m.group() to an ArrayList just outputs the entire page source. This is how I add it allMatches.add(m.group());